# When using imread, I can't build

Tags: opencv, compiler-errors, vscode-extensions, linker-errors, esp32

I've made a project on esp-idf for the ESP32-CAM AIthinker, which uses a portable version of OpenCV seen in [text](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv/tree/master).
Everything seems to be working fine, except for the function imread().

Whenever I put that on the code I can't compile with VS Code. The error is one of the following:

```
[6/7] Linking CXX executable cam-test.elf
FAILED: cam-test.elf
```

```
[3/7] Building CXX object esp-idf/m...f_main.dir/hello_world_main.cpp.obj
FAILED: esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/hello_world_main.cpp.obj
```

This also happens with anything coming from the imgcodecs library.
The core library however works fine.